# terragrunt not accepting vars files

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code, terragrunt

I am trying to use a 2-repo IaC with the so called back-end being in the form of `terragrunt` modules and the front-end (or `live`) with the instantiation of such modules that are being filled in with variables.

The image below depicts the structure of those 2 repos (`terragrunt` being the back-end and `terraform-live` the live one as the name implies).

[image]

In my `terragrunt/aws-vpc/variables.tf`, there is the following declaration:

```
variable "remote_state_bucket" {
  description = "The bucket containing the terraform remote state"
}
```

However, when trying to perform a `terragrunt apply` in the live directory, i get the following:

```
var.remote_state_bucket
  The bucket containing the terraform remote state

  Enter a value:
```

Here is my `terraform-live/environments/staging/terragrunt.hcl`

```
  remote_state {
    backend = "s3"
    config = {
      bucket  = "my-bucket-staging"
      key  = "terraform/state/var.env_name/${path_relative_to_include()}"
      region = "eu-west-1"
    }
  }
  # Configure root level variables that all resources can inherit
  terraform {
    extra_arguments "extra_args" {
      commands = "${get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()}"
      optional_var_files = [
          "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/${find_in_parent_folders("config.tfvars", "ignore")}",
          "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/${find_in_parent_folders("secrets.auto.tfvars", "ignore")}",
      ]
    }
  }
```

What is more, the variable seems to be declared in one of the files that `terragrunt` is instructed to read variables from:

```
➢  cat terraform-live/environments/staging/config.tfvars
remote_state_bucket = "pkaramol-staging"
```

Why is `terragrunt` (or `terraform` ?) unable to read the specific variable?

```
➢  terragrunt --version
terragrunt version v0.19.29

➢  terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `config.tfvars` is not in a parent folder :)

`find_in_parent_folders` looks in parent folders, but not in the current folder. And your `config.tfvars` is in the same folder as your `terragrunt.hcl`.

Try using something like:

```
optional_var_files = [
    "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/config.tfvars",
    "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/secrets.auto.tfvars",
]
```